# Why does a SATA-to-USB adapter freeze data transfers?

Tags: sata

My VE633E SATA-USB adapter has one SATA light and one other IDE light.

They blink if the computer accesses the drive, but not if the drive sends data (e.g. C1/C2 scans) to PCs.

But they are close to meaningless, because SATA also sometimes shines on UltraATA usage. Sometimes it blinks parallel to IDE, sometimes opposite.

But when using the SATA side with a TS-H653B optical drive, this happens on all of multiple tested computers:

- Both SATA and IDE light on VE633E go on. SATA blinks for a few seconds.

  - PC reads data for a few seconds.
  - SATA light goes off, IDE stays on.
  - PC stops reading data, drive tray can only be opened via eject button on drive itself, PC stuck on reading request forever.
  - VE633E pulled from drive: still stuck on reading request.
  - USB cable to adapter pulled, PC unfreezes.
  - USB cable and SATA adapter reconnected, no response by PC.
  - External power to SATA adapter disabled and re-enabled; SATA adapter resueable.

The same effect also happens to other drives, especially SATA drives, but relatively rarely. E.g. GDR-H20N for DVD+RW after reading around  750MB and DVD-ROM somewhere between 1.3GB to 1.9GB.

What is a technical explaination?

The problem is somewhere inside the VE633E

Answer (score 1):

Are you using an extension cable or hub? I find if I have an extension lead before my SATA to USB adapter the adapter will freeze midway through the transfer.. however plugged in directly into the back of the PC it will be fine for hundreds of gigabytes.

It's all due to high volume transfers not being able to cope over poor quality cables.. but day to day low throughput usage etc. is fine.

Comment: With USB hub, it does not work **at all.** Without USB hub, some devices work.

Comment: But why does it freeze up permanently (until poweroff?).